# Reverse DNS Resolution Not Working After Installing Bind9 in Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, bind9

I installed DNS Server (bind9) in my ubuntu server and I am able to do name resolution from hostname to ip address using nslooup and dig; however when I try to do reverse lookups I get an error

```
nslookup 192.168.137.5 
** server can't find 5.137.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

that ip address is the ip address of the local server which is also the nameserver with bind9 installed.
if I do forward lookups works just fine

```
nslookup example.com
Server:         192.168.137.5
Address:        192.168.137.5#53

Name:   example.com
Address: 192.168.137.5
Name:   example.com
Address: ::1
```

Here are my configuration files 3 in total: named.config.local, forward.example.com, reverse.example.com
named.conf.local

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/forward.example.com";
};

zone "137.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/reverse.example.com";
};
```

forward.example.com

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      home-server.example.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.137.5
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
home-server     IN      A       192.168.137.5
wintop  IN      A       192.168.137.1
```

reverse.example.com

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      home-server.
@       IN      PTR     example.com.
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
home-server     IN      A       192.168.137.5
host    IN      A       192.168.137.5
wintop  IN      A       192.168.137.1
10      IN      PTR     home-server.example.com.
11      IN      PTR     wintop.example.com.
```

Comment: Note that this isn't Unix and Linux specific.  This is a how-to-write-zone-files-correctly thing, and could occur on any platform where one could run BIND.  Also note that you can self-answer your question by asking yourself one simple thing: Where do you think in all that that you have actually specified a `ptr` resource record (set), or a resource record set of any type for that matter, for the domain name `5.137.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`?

Comment: that's why I came here looking for answer, but reading yours there's nothing that says this is where is wrong... you just ask more questions. reminds me of the guy in Office Space asking about the TPS reports... rhetoric questioning.. redundant questioning..  I'm too smart to answer so I will make you feel even dumber bla bla bla thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `forward.example.com` zone file, your `reverse.example.com` zone file should look like this:

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN 137.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
@       IN      NS      example.com.
5       IN      PTR     example.com.
1       IN      PTR     wintop.example.com.
```

There should be no `A` nor `AAAA` records in reverse zones, except perhaps as glue records in sub-zone delegations.

Your original reverse zone file was insisting that IP address 192.168.137.10 would be `home-server.example.com` and 192.168.137.11 would be `wintop.example.com`, which would be inconsistent with your forward zone.

And claiming IPv6 localhost address `::1` is just silly. In the reverse zone it has no effect at all, in the forward zone, it is just wrong. When a client asks "Where is `home-server.example.com`?", your forward zone would have the server answer: "For IPv4, it's 192.168.137.5; for IPv6, it's ::1." Then the client would think: "Huh. I'm IPv6-capable like basically all modern OSs since Windows Vista, so this name was just a fancy way of pointing to... me? Sweet, I don't have to make any external network connection to reach it after all! I can handle the request all by myself!" ...And unless the request actually came from `home-server.example.com`, that would probably not be what you meant to happen.

Remember that the DNS server just delivers the records to the client with no interpretation at all; the client is the one that actually uses the information.

You might also have to consider which one would be the *canonical* name of 192.168.137.5: is it `home-server.example.com` or just `example.com`? You might have to make one of the names an alias for the other (a CNAME record); otherwise you might have problems with getting SSL/TLS certificates validated successfully for both names.

So your forward zone perhaps should look like this:

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN example.com.
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.137.5
home-server     IN      CNAME example.com.
wintop  IN      A       192.168.137.1
```